# Using NFC scanning functionality in React apps with Capacitor

Tags: reactjs, cordova, cordova-plugins, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am trying to build a basic barebones app for testing purposes in which you can scan an NFC tag and it will display its content. I am using React for web, and wrapping it with Capacitor. I am mainly testing in xcode/ios.

I tried phonetag-nfc and capacitor-nfc but they don't seem to be working properly. There is always an error when reading the tag, but the error itself is empty.

Did someone succeed with any library? Are there any other steps that I should take to enable NFC for my app? I don't want to publish it or something, it's just for testing now. What library would you recommend for this use case?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.